# My cipher() function does not seem to support uppercase letters

Tags: c++, c, char, encryption

Here is my function:

```
// Helper function for cipher()
void cipherc(char& c, int key)
{
    if (isupper(c)) {
        c -= 'A';
    } else {
        c -= 'a';
    }

    c += key;
    c %= MAX_KEY;

    if (isupper(c)) {
       c += 'A';
    } else {
        c += 'a';
    }
}
```

I designed it to support uppercase letters, and I though this would work. Apparantly I have no idea what i'm doing. If someone could show me a better way to do this or fix this that would be great. I would like to (hopefully) keep the function the same, taking `char&` and `int` and returning `void`.

Comment: What exactly is the problem?

Comment: There's little chance of the second `isupper` returning the desired result after you modify `c`.

Comment: Right! that makes sense...

Comment: The problem was that uppercase letters were becoming lowercase

Comment: @Pocketkid2 either close this question or post an answer and accept it

Answer (score 0):

try code like that:

```
   char d = isupper(c) ? 'A' : 'a';
   c -= d;
   c += key;
   c %= MAX_KEY;
   c += d;
```